# Использование функции в атрибуте Authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день!
Возник пробел в знаниях, не знаю как его заполнить :(
В общем, имеется проект asp.net mvc, в нем на каждом методе контроллера есть фильтр авторизации

```
[Authorize(Users = "user@mail.com")]
```

И есть функция, которая формирует строку разрешенных юзеров в виде "user1@mail.com, user2@mail.com, user3@mail.com". Выглядит допустим так

```
private string getAllowedUsers(string method) { }
```

Как мне всунуть эту функцию в фильтр, чтобы в итоге получилось что-то вроде

```
[Authorize(Users = getAllowedUsers(method))]
```

В таком виде естественно не срабатывает, требует объект. Как надо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант первый - использовать роли:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "...")]
```

Для этого надо на этапе аутентификации пользователя вычислять его роли заранее.

Вариант второй - унаследуйтесь от [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), переопределите метод [`AutorizeCore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460355(v=vs.118).aspx) - и пишите там любую свою логику.

Comment: У нас авторизация через аккаунты организации, там нет ролей

Comment: А что мешает их добавить?.. В любом случае, я написал два варианта. Второму варианту роли не нужны.

Answer (score 2):

В атрибутах можно использовать только константные значения. В ASP.NET MVC существует такое понятие как роли пользователей. В вашем случае целесообразно использовать этот функционал.

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
```

Допускается также указывать несколько ролей и конкретных пользователей:

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin,user", Users="user1@mail.com")]
```

Создание ролей и пользователей выглядит следующим образом:

```
var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

// создаем две роли
var role1 = new IdentityRole { Name = "admin" };
var role2 = new IdentityRole { Name = "user" };

// добавляем роли в бд
roleManager.Create(role1);
roleManager.Create(role2);

// создаем пользователей
var admin = new ApplicationUser { Email = "somemail@mail.ru", UserName = "somemail@mail.ru" };
string password = "ad46D_ewr3";
var result = userManager.Create(admin, password);

// если создание пользователя прошло успешно
if(result.Succeeded)
{
    // добавляем для пользователя роль
    userManager.AddToRole(admin.Id, role1.Name);
    userManager.AddToRole(admin.Id, role2.Name);
}
```

Пример отсюда: [Работа с ролями в AspNet Identity](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/12.4.php)

Comment: 600 пользователей, и авторизуются они через Azure Active Directory. Не подходит такой вариант.

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев напротив, авторизация на основе ролей вместе с Active Directory получается очень удобной!

Comment: @PavelMayorov создавать сначала роли а потом вручную всех добавлять? очень удобно, действительно.

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев внутри getAllowedUsers вы тоже вручную делаете - или у вас уже какое-то решение есть? Так почему бы его не использовать?

Comment: @PavelMayorov представьте ситуацию, что к методу сначала доступ имело 2 группы пользователей, а теперь нужно дать доступ третьей. Не буду же я заходить и вручную дописывать название группы в атрибут, должен быть способ подставить туда строковое значение, рассчитаное в ходе работы приложения

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев во-первых, эту проблему можно решить средствами AD: надо просто создать отдельную группу, чье имя никогда не будет меняться. И сделать две группы членами этой новой группы. Когда нужна третья - ок, ее тоже добавляем в члены.

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев во-вторых, совершенно необязательно чтобы роли были привязаны к группам в AD!

Comment: @PavelMayorov плодить группы заказчик запретил. А без привязки получаем тот-же геморрой с занесением существующих пользователей в группы вручную

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев у вас сейчас как работает getAllowedUsers? Почему вы не можете "вывернуть" этот алгоритм и искать для пользователя его роли?

Comment: @PavelMayorov есть список пользователей и разрешенных методов для них. выбирает пользователей, которым разрешен текущий метод и собирает их в одну строку

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев а сам список вы как заполняли? Вручную? :)

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев но не важно. Смотрите: называем "разрешенный метод" из списка ролью... и у нас получается авторизация на основе ролей!